# Is it possible to transfer information through js?

Tags: javascript

It may not be a good question, but is it possible to transfer local values from a user to a public text file using JS?

For example, I want to write the IP value of a user ( var IP = ... ) to a text file ([www.blabla.com/iplist.txt](http://www.blabla.com/iplist.txt) ).

Comment: Not with only javascript.  The client has to make a web request to a shared resource (a server) to perform the update to the shared file.

Comment: "Not with only javascript" is disregarding that the server could be a nodejs server.

Comment: Also, if you are wanting to save the user's IP, you don't need any client side coding to do it. You can write that script all server side, like PHP,  .net etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With only JavaScript? Yes. With only browser-based JavaScript and nothing else? No. :-)

You need

1. A place that stores the file so that when people go to look at it, they can get it (e.g., a server of some kind), and
2. Some means of modifying the file that that server provides when people go to it, which you can't do from browser-hosted JavaScript

You could use a Node.js-based server (for instance), or some cloud provider where you don't care what the server tech is, but you'll need a server.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, guys! I will use PHP for that.